# Avoiding duplicate code in two controllers in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have a route in Laravel 5.1 that will accept a generic permalink and will need to determine what object it belongs to (for example is it a permalink for a "Blog" or a "Story"?).

The route looks like this:

```
// .... Every other route in the routes.php file //
Route::get('{generic_url}', 'CMSController@generic');
```

Then the code in the my controller looks like this:

```
public function generic($generic_url) {
    $blog = Blog::where('permalink', $generic_url)->first();
    if(!is_null($blog)) {
        // Load a blog entry page
    }

    // Something basically the same as above but for Story
}
```

I also have this route in my routes.php file to view a blog post:

```
Route::get('/blog/{blog_id}', 'BlogController@view');
```

The purpose of that second route was for me rough in the view a blog post page as well as a quick way for me to debug a particular post.

I am hoping to avoid having to put view code in two separate controllers. My first thought was to try and find a way to have CMSController call the view action in the BlogController. It sounds like a terrible idea to me and some searching around confirms that it is a terrible idea.

My question is, what is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: Did you consider using a trait? That's what I tend to use to de-duplicate code if it doesn't make sense to use an abstract base class or a dependency injected via the constructor or a setter method.

Comment: I've never used traits before, but it looks like it shows promise. Can you tell me where you would place a trait in a Laravel project?

Comment: Does it act exactly like a class with respect to where it should be located?

Comment: The trait worked great. If you make an actual answer, I will make it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I decided to add a static method to my Blog model and place it in the controllers:

```
return Blog::RenderFrontendView($blog_id);
```

I know this seems a bit strange considering I have already loaded the model in one of the spots I am using this code, but in the context of what I am doing it makes sense. It looks in the cache to retrieve all the info and I intend to do further optimization to only load the ID instead of the entire model.

Update: I am no longer using this method as using a trait was a much better solution